# JQuery On Select change assign value to variable and reload script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible at all to be able to assign the selected value of a select and assign it to the variable of a script and re-run the script?

Here is my current code sample:

```
<select onchange="reload_script;">
  <option value="123">Select 123</option>
  <option value="456">Select 456</option>
<select>

<div id="123">
    <a href="http://same.com/index.do?n=152991">link title</a>
    <br/><br/>
    <a href="http://some.com/">Link</a>
</div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var code = '123' // <-- THIS VARIABLE WOULD BE THE VALUE OF THE SELECTED DROPDOWN VALUE
</script>
```

See: var code = '123' .... That's what's changed when the select box is changed ... then I would need the script to re-run...

Is this possible at all?

Comment: What script do you need to re-execute?

Comment: You need what script to re-run?? Please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<select onchange="reload_script();">
  <option value="123">Select 123</option>
  <option value="456">Select 456</option>
<select>

<div id="123">
    <a href="http://same.com/index.do?n=152991">link title</a>
    <br/><br/>
    <a href="http://some.com/">Link</a>
</div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var code = '123' // <-- THIS VARIABLE WOULD BE THE VALUE OF THE SELECTED DROPDOWN VALUE
function script_to_run()
{
//do code here
}

// Call the script one time on page load (only if you need it on page load)
script_to_run();

function reload_script()
{
  script_to_run();//run again
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use jQuery you can always bind [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event:

```
var code = "123";
$("#mySelect").on("change", function() {
    code = this.value;
    reload_script();
});
```

Otherwise, in plain JavaScript it may look like this:

```
var code = "123";
document.getElementById("mySelect").onchange = function() {
    code = this.value;
    reload_script();
};
```